# resizable column borders in footer

Tags: html, css, layout

i want to have a footer with tree columns, a title for each and some links under each title.and i want to have a border line in the middle of the space between the columns, but i want the space between the columns to be flexible(some%of the whole page width so the columns stay next to each other as far as possible when the window is resized) note that adding like 15% padding doesn't work bc the text in each column has a length by itself which does not change as you resize the window(in case you dont understand what i mean by that try to test your code before answering the question!)
this is my css:

```
div.footer{
padding:15px 8%;
margin:0px;
display:inline-block;
}
div#footerR{
float:right;
}
div#footerL{
float:left;
}
footer{
text-align:center;
}
```

and here is my html

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer" id="footerR">
        <h1>توضیحات</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="footer" id="footerC">
        <h1>اخبار</h1>
        <h4><a>این خبر اولین خبر در این سایت است</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div class="footer" id="footerL">
        <h1>پیوند ها</h1>
    </div>
</footer>
```

btw please mention if you can come up with a whole new better way for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1mwfm82g) is what i do with your code

```
div.footer {
    padding:15px 8%;
    margin:0px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:33.333%; /*New attribute - make each col have 33% width of the browser*/
}
div#footerR {
    float:right;
}
div#footerL {
    float:left;
}
div#footerC { /*New define*/
    float:left; /*New attribute*/
    position:relative; /*New attribute*/
}
div#footerC:before { /*New define*/
    content : "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%; /*New attribute - you can increase or decrease like you see fit (affect the position of the line separate from top)*/
    left: 0;
    height:75%; /*New attribute - you can increase or decrease like you see fit (affect the height of the line)*/
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    width:100%;
}
div#footerC, div#footerL, div#footerR { /*New define - with attributes to make your col stay the same width no matter your padding are*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer {
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    display:flex; /*New attribute - make your cols always the same height*/
}
```

Hope this is what you want! Otherwise tell me where i do wrong with your intend.
UPDATE [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1mwfm82g/2/)

Comment: great!thank you!now i want to make the line in between start from a little lower place like from next to the links!i dont want it to start from the top of the div box.btw do you thing using divs and footer like i did is the best way to do this or you recommend another way?

Comment: @aran see my edited for your wish, btw i can't think any way to do this better, beside IMO this do what you want just fine

Comment: :wow that was so great!thank you so much!this was exactly what i wanted!but can you explain to me please what is that :before and that content:""; and why didnt you put that float left and position relative also in the :before part?

Comment: @aran about :before (and it sibling :after) and content:"" you can read on google or [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) (too long for a comment); no need float left in `:before` because it position relate with #footerC (not really need float left in that col too - you can delete it and the demo still work the same but i still add like a habit of myself); in `:before` must be position absolute (with position relative in it parent - #footerC) to make sure it stay the same position with it parent or it will run wild (you can search for position property too)